# How do I use SetNotifyCallbackFunction() in Microsoft SAPI?

Tags: c++, callback, sapi

I am working with the Microsoft Speech API and I am stuck trying to understand one of the functions. The function is called `SetNotifyCallbackFunction()` which is part of [ISpNotifySource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717961(v=vs.85).aspx). The problem I am having is with the first parameter which is the callback function. I could not find an example of this on MSDN or an example online. The first parameter has the type of `SPNOTIFYCALLBACK` which I could find little information of online. I have tried declaring a func called `testCallback()` but I keep getting an error saying that the first parameter must be of type `SPNOTIFYCALLBACK`.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<sphelper.h>
#include <sapi.h>

int main() {

    RESULT hr = S_OK;
    CComPtr<ISpRecoContext> g_cpRecoCtxt;

    hr = g_cpRecoCtxt->SetNotifyCallbackFunction(testCallback, NULL, NULL);

}

void testCallback() {
// Some code here..
}
```

Does anyone know how I can implement a callback so that I can use `SetNotifyCallbackFunction()`?

Comment: This might help:  https://github.com/rpavlik/vrjuggler-2.2-debs/blob/0118f3fa3cd304f312fb84e717e1ecc091225496/modules/gadgeteer/drivers/Microsoft/SpeechRecognition/MSFTSpeechServerManager.cpp Looking at the header file, you can see it's not a void, but expects SPNOTIFYCALLBACK as the return type

Comment: Copy-paste from @Tim's link: `void __stdcall testCallback(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)`

Answer (score 2):

I took a gander at the github listed in the comments above in your question, and it seemed to be a bit more complicated than it really needed to be for a simple one-off test program. Also, if you're just going to implement a class that contains all of the COM pointers, you probably don't want to use SetNotifyCallbackFunction, and have your class implement SetNotifyCallbackInterface instead.

```
#include <sapi.h>
#include <sphelper.h>
#include <conio.h>

CComPtr<ISpRecognizer> g_cpEngine;
CComPtr<ISpRecoContext> g_cpContext;
CComPtr<ISpRecoGrammar> g_cpGrammar;

void __stdcall testCallback(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    CSpEvent evt;
    ISpRecoResult* pPhrase;
    LPWSTR *text;
    bool exit = false;
    //text = new LPWSTR(L"");
    HANDLE waitHandle = NULL;
    waitHandle = g_cpContext->GetNotifyEventHandle();
    do{
        WaitForSingleObject(waitHandle, INFINITE);
        while (g_cpContext != NULL && evt.GetFrom(g_cpContext) == S_OK)
        {
        // Look at recognition event only
            switch (evt.eEventId)
            {
                case SPEI_RECOGNITION:
                    pPhrase = evt.RecoResult();
                    text = new LPWSTR(L"");
                    pPhrase->GetText(SP_GETWHOLEPHRASE, SP_GETWHOLEPHRASE, TRUE, text, NULL);

                    wprintf(L"%ls\n", *text);
                    if(wcscmp(L"Exit",*text) == 0){
                        exit = true;
                    }
                    delete[] text;
                break;

                case SPEI_FALSE_RECOGNITION:
                    wprintf(L"False Reco\n");
                break;
            }
        }

    }while(!exit && g_cpContext != NULL);
    if(g_cpEngine)
        g_cpEngine->SetRecoState(SPRECOSTATE::SPRST_INACTIVE);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    HANDLE waitHandle;
    ULONGLONG ullEvents;
    DWORD dwRetVal;
    HANDLE thread;
    ullEvents = SPFEI(SPEI_RECOGNITION) | SPFEI(SPEI_FALSE_RECOGNITION);
    waitHandle = NULL;

    dwRetVal = 0;
    ::CoInitialize(NULL);
    hr = g_cpEngine.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SpSharedRecognizer);
    hr = g_cpEngine->CreateRecoContext( &g_cpContext );
    hr = g_cpContext->SetAudioOptions(SPAO_NONE, NULL, NULL);
    hr = g_cpContext->CreateGrammar(NULL,&g_cpGrammar);
    hr = g_cpContext->SetInterest(ullEvents,ullEvents);
    hr = g_cpContext->SetNotifyCallbackFunction(testCallback, NULL, NULL);
    hr = g_cpGrammar->SetDictationState(SPRULESTATE::SPRS_ACTIVE);
    hr = g_cpEngine->SetRecoState(SPRECOSTATE::SPRST_ACTIVE);

    thread = ::CreateThread(NULL,0,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)testCallback,NULL,NULL,NULL);

    puts("Press any key to continue...");
    getch();

    g_cpGrammar.Release();
    g_cpContext.Release();
    g_cpEngine.Release();
    ::CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

This program has no error handling, mind you, and it uses getch() to keep it from just exiting and cleaning up. You'll have to find your own way of keeping your program busy while you handle events from the recognizer.